# Mysqli connect, custom error message not showing up

Tags: php, html, xampp

I'm doing a tutorial from one guy and he have a code like that:

```
<?php

require_once "connect.php";

$polaczenie = @new mysqli($host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);

if ($polaczenie->connect_errno != 0) {
    echo "Error: " . $polaczenie->connect_errno;
} else {
    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $haslo = $_POST['haslo'];

    echo "It works!";

    $polaczenie->close();
}

?>
```

I can't figure out why the Error: errno message doesn't show up.

When I'm doing tests just regular error message show up and not my custom. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP 8.1.0, the default setting for `mysqli_report()` has been to raise an exception instead of setting the error state in the `mysqli` object. So use an exception handler instead of checking `$polaczenie->connect_errno`.

```
try {
    $polaczenie = @new mysqli($host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);

    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $haslo = $_POST['haslo'];

    echo "It works!";

    $polaczenie->close();
} catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $polaczenie->getCode();
}
```

You can also go back to the old behavior with

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_OFF);
```